# Development device token is different from production one?

Tags: objective-c, certificate, push-notification

i have a problem with the push notification, working like a charm in development but not in production... I've searched for a solution, and from what i've read seems that device token of a device generated in development is different from what generated when the app is downloaded from the app store.. Could it be?

The php script that send notification seems to connect and send the notification correctly, so i'm guessing if the problem is only with my personal device, because the device token used to send it the notification was generated when i was developing...

Comment: Yes they are different.

Comment: there's a way to delete completely all the info about my app from my iphone, so the app can ask me another time the authorization for enable push notification? I store the device token in my db only in that moment...

Comment: @ElisabettaFalivene delete your app from device. Wait for 1 day or set your clock one day ahead. Restart your device. Install again.

Comment: Every time your app starts, you need to submit the device token to your server. The device token is unique for each user, and can change at any time. To make development easier, you may want to tell the server whether the device token you are sending is for the sandbox or production environment. Finally, may want to store a few device tokens for each user, since they may have multiple devices.

Comment: what do you mean that change at any time? If i submit the token every time and it change, i will have inactive token... Gets complicated... How i can say to the server if the token is for development or production? (How can I know it??) And you seem to separate the concept of user from device token.. I'm not understanding

Comment: you should send the token to your server every time you receive one from apple, don't store it in the device db

Comment: it's not in the device db. When the app start i call an external php script with the device token as variable that adds the token in an online db

Comment: You should call this script not only when user allows push notification for your app.